# Error when running jasmine and selenium-webdriver based tests

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, selenium-chromedriver

I am in the process of creating some end to end tests for my website using selenium webdriver and jasmine. I tried searching for good beginners tutorial. I ended up with [this tutorial](http://www.techinsight.io/review/devops-and-automation/browser-automation-using-selenium-webdriver-and-nodejs/) which helped me to progress till the step of running the end to end tests. I have tried to follow the tutorial exactly the way it is described there including same directory names. I am using Chrome  browser and installed chromedriver. When I run the tests using

```
$ jasmine spec\integration-test.js
```

as stated there, I get a bunch of timeout errors as follows. It also opens up two Chrome windows with `data:,` as URL. I spent some time trying to figure it out, but seem to be going no where. Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if any more information is required.

```
Started
FF

Failures:
1) Selenium Tutorial Should be on the home page
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:121:15)
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:121:15)
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:121:15)

2) Selenium Tutorial Has a working nav
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:121:15)
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:121:15)
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:121:15)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your jasmine config: (increase as necessary)

```
"default_timeout_interval": 5000
```

Comment: I should explain more: Chrome isn't loading the page fast enough and Jasmine thinks it's timing out. Adding this will let Chrome actually load the page before the test starts.

Comment: Thanks for the response Andy Poquette, I actually happened to move on to an alternative approach using Phantomjs and Mocha for now. Only reason for that choice was that it gave me a quicker starting point with some exact code samples that i needed for my use case. I still would like to get my selenium webdriver-jasmine code working. If i remember correctly i did try increasing the time to a very large number, but i will check it again in couple of days to make sure i really did that and post back if i am able to get it working with your suggestion.

Comment: Changing this value to 20000 did work for me. I thought i tried it previously, it seems that i was mistaken somewhere. But it works now :-). Thanks a ton Andy Poquette.

Comment: It's an odd problem as sometimes that number seems to work and sometimes it doesn't. I think you can also set:

jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 40000

Comment: Another thing to mention is to make sure you add the -timeout parameter when you start your selenium server, and increase that as necessary.